# onesignal tokens stop working after apple push notification certificate renew

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

Well lets me explain,

My Apple push notification certification expired then i generate a new one and changed it in apple certifications but after it apple users stopped receiving pushs but new users are receiving it fine.

Well sound like that old tokens get invalid but i don't know for sure, someone faced it before? there is some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen. Did you generate a dual Sandbox & Production cert as mentioned in our [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate#section-2-enable-push-notifications-and-apply-the-certification-request-to-generate-certificate)? Players who were subscribed using one cert type won't transfer to the other cert type.

Please contact our support channel at OneSignal.com for further assistance. Cheers